# Why do my shapes and images disappear on my panel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, shapes

I have used the `paintComponent` method to draw shapes on my panel. However, every time I minimize the frame or resize it, they disappear. Not sure what to add to my code.

```
   public class ShapePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener{

    int a,b,c,d;
    Graphics2D g2D;
    private Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D(a,b,c-a,d-b);

    public ShapePanel(){

    addMouseListener(this);
    setLayout(new GridLayout());
}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.draw(rect);
    repaint();

}


   //get methods for coordinates: MousePressed, MouseReleased
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't call `repaint()` under the `paintComponent` method. Also, do `super.paintComponent(g)` the first thing in your `paintComponent` method.

Update: your code has a lot of compile errors. However, please see below a list of things to change:

- `new Rectangle2D(a, b, c, d)` should be new `Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 100, 100);` or anyway, a, b, c and d should have some values, otherwise they are all zero, so no rectangle
- name the class the same both in definition and in constructor
- implement `mouseClicked`, `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`
- remove `g2D.draw()` from `actionPerformed` and don't keep a reference to `g2D` in the class.

I have the full code that is working if you need it.

Comment: If I do this I can't see any rectangles on my panel?

Comment: I spotted some errors already, but please post the entire class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23214/discussion-between-nsc010-and-dan)